# Calculate triangle offset

Tags: geometry, triangles

Assume I put a board (in red) behind the black-outlined area. I draw a line against the top-right angled side so I can get cut the triangle off the board so that it will fit flush inside the outline.

[image]

If I cut out the triangle I am left with (pic 2). The cut-out board is x too short. I know why this is, but I don't know how to calculate the green line. There are various reasons why I need to do it this way, none pertinent to the question (it involves scribing in carpentry).

Should the green line be equal to the blue line? I've laid it out in a grid in photoshop with perfect angles but, as you can see, it doesn't appear to be the case in the illustrations (but maybe my drawing is off). I feel like I should be taking the hypotenuse into account.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is extremely confusing.  Do you mean you cannot cut where you intend to?  What is the difference between the black and red diagonal lines?  What is the left black line in the first picture which disappeared in the second.  Which dimensions match between the two pictures?

Comment: I'm putting a board behind a wall (black outline) and to the left a 'few inches' (say x) within an outline to get the angle so I can cut out the top triangle. Because the board is offset x when I marked- out the triangle and subsequently cut it, the board is not flush (pic 2) e.g. it doesnt fit inside the outline, there is a space. TL;DR: I'm asking is that space (green line) equal to x (blue line) if I move the entire red outline from x outside of the outline, to overlapping the outline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have drawn a figure below.  You are asking if the distance between lines $JI$ and $ED$ is the same as $FA$.  It is not.  If $\theta=\angle DEL$ we have the distance between $JI$ and $ED$ is $FA \sin \theta$.  Draw a perpendicular from E and you get a right triangle that shows it.

[image]

Comment: Not quite the question I was asking. In this context, it is more if FA and JE are equal. But not really. I've added another picture for clarity. I appreciate you bearing with me. I'm not that great at math, but I'm always interested in seeing/exploring practical applications in diy stuff.

Comment: FA and JE are equal because they are both horizontal.  Your green line is at an angle.  That is the point.  It is therefore shorter.  Just take a ruler to your drawing.

Comment: I realize that. I guess it was the way you were presenting it that confused me. In this context then how would one calculate the distance (e.g. green line)?

Comment: I showed it.  It is $FA \sin \theta$

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit slow. Got it now! Awesome.